# Reputation graph does not appear if over ~two years

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

I just came across the [reputation graph on my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234256/mooseman?tab=reputation&sort=graph) and tried to load for the past two years. Because of how narrow each day's bar is, it does not appear at all unless I zoom in the page.

Can each bar be given a minimum width, and the graph container allowed to be scrolled horizontally if it overflows?

---

I'm not sure how easily this will be reproduced, so I here's a screenshot:
[image]